# remove or update Google play service on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

i programmed an android app which uses the google maps api v2. i want to test it on the emulator, but to show the map it has a little bit problems. i googled and found the articel, that i have to install to packages (vending.apk, android.gms.apk). i downloaded the packages and installed it. what i did not know is, the installed android.gms.apk is not up to date. when i run the app on the emulator, it shows an button an a message: ...update Google Play services. And now i found the newest version of the .gms.apk. but i am not able to remove or update the google play services on the emulator, because i became the following message from the cmd:

[image]

is there a solution for these problem? thx in advance

Comment: adb install -r  "com.google....  Use the -r parameter when reinstalling.

Comment: thx for your comment, but it doesnt worked. :/

Comment: Use the official Google APIs and the 4.2.2 image as described in this Stack Overflow answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc/17245326#17245326

Answer (score 5):

Installing google service packages; gms and vending

- Be sure that emulator started
- Copy com.google.android.gms-19032013.apk and com.google.android.vending-19032013.apk files to < bundle root >\sdk\platform-tools from my blog.
- Open command prompt and go to < bundel root >\sdk\platform-tools
- then run command adb install com.google.android.gms-19032013.apk
- then run command adb install com.android.vending-19032013.apk
  if it says already exits then run commands
      -adb uninstall com.android.vending
      -adb uninstall com.google.android.gms

I had similar problems so I prepared step by step tutorial to show how you can use google map android v2 on emulator(android 4.2.2) have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: "adb install -r com.google.android.gms" is a much more convenient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

adb uninstall cannot work for system apps is what I am finding out. And Vending and gms are system apps. Therefore adb uninstall com.android.vending causes a failure even if I su. So is there no resolution to this problem?

I can't install it even if I use -r because the certificates are different.

Answer (score 0):

you should try it on android instead of google api's , i am sure it will work for you. because google api's have already installed these apk's.

Answer (score 0):

the below link help you to step by step about google android map

http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

download the package from following link

by entering package name

http://www.filecrop.com/search.php?w=com.google.android.gms-19032013.apk&size_i=0&size_f=100000000&engine_d=1&engine_h=1&engine_e=1&engine_m=1&engine_4=1

Answer (score 0):

user2414493 My original reason to try and reinstall is because even with google API 19 my App which mind you works on Samsung s3 and Nexus 4 crashes. Right before it crashes it prints this

Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 4033530.

Infact on google API 19 even google Maps is not working completely! I can't get my current location even though I have internet connection and 4g emulated.