# Android : Error to install Google play services in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I am using Google Maps on the Android emulator, but it is asking me to install Google Play Services but when I click on install it is crashing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]What you need to do is:

1. Install Google Play Services and Google APis from the Android SDK Manager.
2. Create an AVD (Android Virtual Device) with a target:  Google APIs. The device should run android 4.2 or higher.

For more information check here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Making new  emulator with X86 architecture worked for me .

Answer (score -1):

This is a hack from one of the posts on SO that I used and had setup on my machine. Dont have the link right now, if someone could post that please, this is just a dump from back then that I had copied.

1.) Create a new emulator

2.) For device choose "5.1'' WVGA (480 x 800: mdpi)", Target choose "Android 4.1.2 - API level 16", "CPU/ABI" choose "ARM" and The rest choose defaults

3.) Start the emulator

install [com.android.vending-1.apk](http://www.filedropper.com/comandroidvending-1) and [com.google.android.gms-1.apk](http://www.filedropper.com/comgoogleandroidgms-1) via ADB install command

Voila! It worked for me. Last I checked this was only possible otherwise officialy on devices. But that is 2012 December knowledge, I havent checked again