# Test Google maps on emulator - CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Tags: android, emulation, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to my app using google maps **v2 in my emulator**, and I can't.

Let's see what I intented to do :

Use  Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17 like they says :

[Google Play Services in emulator, implementing Google Plus login button etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc)

Use an emulator 3.2.2, and install manually **com.android.vending.apk** and **com.google.android.gms.apk**

I tried to install it on **Genymotion**.

All the techniques give me the same error :

`java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized`

I also tried to use BlueStacks and it gave me the error al install apk: 
**INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES**

Nevertheless, my app works fine one Samsung fame ( api14) and htc nexus one ( api 10)
is there any solution to run google maps in emulator ( any api version)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, the solution is:

In Emulator you should update Google Play services. Head over to Play Store and to My apps & games for running updates. After that, try your app again in Emulator.