# Google Play Services has to be updated for my app to run on emulator, Need to run the app on emulator only as I have to find the id's.

Tags: android, android-emulator, automation, robotium, hierarchyviewer

I am trying to automate an android application using Robotium. I am trying to find the id's of the elements using Hierarchyviewer on the emulator. When I launch my app on the emulator it says "Update Google Play Services" and app closes. I tried all the solutions to updated Google Play Services on Emaultor- NO USE. Tried with AVD - Google API 4.2.2 as well.
Please let me how do I proceed from here.

Comment: Check out similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc

Comment: Thanks GrIsHu, I have read that post also and tried with that AVD also. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [GrIsHu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839336/grishu) you should be able to follow what is on that page. If you really cannot get that to work, I might suggest trying to use an alternative emulator [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) This makes it really easy to get new emulators that run fast and also gives you a few extra features.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I am using the Android SDK emulators with Hierarchyviewer to find the object id's ? Can I do the same with Genymotion emulators also ?