# Google Play Services Missing in Emulator (Android 4.4.2)

Tags: android, emulation, google-play-services

For the emulator I have below, I am getting the error message that "Google Play Services not installed on the device".

As per the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), it says that '*The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher*.

Not able to understand if the emulator is running 4.4.2 then why is google play services not present?

[image]

[image]

Some related threads, but no resolution. (adding these just to point out this issue is not a duplicate):
[Related Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-a-android-emulator)
[Related Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Quoting docs

> If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>   Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>   install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform
>   target.

Needs Emulator of Google API"S

See the target in the snap

Snap

[image]

I prefer testing on a real device which has google play services installed

Comment: i tested that but it never run on that emulator too. it says device id is missing.

Comment: @wqrahd check point 3 @ http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: i have to test that again.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for pointing that out - I was testing with the emulator running Android v4.0.0 and was still getting the services not found error even after switching to Google APIs. Upon switching to v4.2.2 Google APIs that fixed the emulator.

Comment: Play Services with maps on Genymotion emulator:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/

Comment: @GabrielKaffka that's using geny motion.

Answer (score 8):

You will not able to test the app using the `Google-Play-Service library` in emulator. In order to test that app in emulator you need to install some system framework in your emulator to  make it work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213598/1405008

Refer the above answer to install Google play service on your emulator.

Comment: @JoeHealy update with reference to another answer which states the same

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to not have the image, download it via the SDK manager:

[image]

Comment: Tons of questions on this one. I am using your solution. I find it strange that it is not installed by default + strange that you have to install it for each emulator. Do you have an idea on the difference Google APIs system image ? I installed them all for simplicity  cause I don't get the point.

Comment: @Ismapro I'm guessing it's probably the most straight forward explanation, to save disk space lol.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Xamarin, I found [a guide on their official forum](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/#3.3.3.installing-android-applications) explaining how to do this:

1. Download the package from the internet. There are many sources for this, [one possible source is the CyanogenMod web site](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Downloads).
2. Start up the Android Player and unlock it.
3. Drag and drop the zip file that you downloaded onto the Android Player.
4. Restart the Android Player.

Hereafter, you might also need to update the Google Play Services from the Google Play Store.

Hope this helps for anyone else who has troubles finding the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Setp 1 : 
Download the following apk files.
                1)com.google.android.gms.apk (https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934534438)
                 2)com.android.vending-4.4.22.apk (https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=23203820527945795)

Step 2 : Create a new AVD without the google API's

Step 3 : Run the AVD (Start the emulator)

Step 4 : Install the downloaded apks using adb .

```
     1)adb install com.google.android.gms-6.7.76_\(1745988-038\)-6776038-minAPI9.apk  
     2)adb install com.android.vending-4.4.22.apk
```

adb come up with android sdks/studio

Step 5 : Create the application in google developer console

Step 6 : Configure the api key in your Androidmanifest.xml and google api version.

Note :
In step1 you need to download the apk based on your Android API level(..18,19,21..) and google play services version (5,5.1,6,6.5......)

This will work 100%.

Comment: Invalid APK file: com.google.android.gms-6.7.76_\(1745988-038\)-6776038-minAPI9.apk

Answer (score 0):

google play service is just a library to create application but in order to use application that use google play service library , you need to install google play in your emulator.and for that it need the unique device id. and device id is only on the real device not have on emulator. so for testing it , you need real android device.