# Android Google Play Services in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I get "Google Play Services" message when I run my app using emulator

[image]

I have checked many posts and they said I have to download Google APIs and Google Play Services

[image]
[image]

and I already did, and I have this code in Gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please Download this one and check again :

[image]

Because you are using

> com.google.android.gms:**play-services**:7.3.0

in dependencies.

Comment: so, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28982894/4409113 - i think you need to install these apps.

Answer (score 0):

Please Install Intel x86 Emulator which is given at the last of the list.

Comment: it just used by emulators, not for Google play services.doesnt make any sense.(for speed up on Intel cpu's)

Comment: You can give this a try - Clean Your Build And then rebuild the solution.