# Cannot test Android app on Android Studio AVD as Google Play Services out of date

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, maps

Seen several S/O links which failed to fix this for me.

Have been developing an Anrdoid App with some use of Google Maps API.
Cannot test said code because it claims:

"Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7895000 but found 6774470"

Instead of showing the map, you get a message plus an "Update" button, which crashes the APP if you click on it. (I believe it's dependent upon Google Play Store being installed)

There is no Google Play store installed on the emulator - this appears to be by design from Google, neither does there appear a way to install it.

The Google Play Services cannot be updated through the settings panel

I have tried downloading the appropriate APK and using adb install, but despite choosing the correct download (current version 6.7.74 1723905-470, downloaded apk 7.8.99 2134222-470) it says: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

I have tried creating a new x86 emulator with a different Android version, same problems persist. Current preference is Google APIs v22 on x86.

How can you test Google Maps on an emulator without paying Google money?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22141089/5482166) answer should solve your issue.