# Android TV emulator with Google APIs

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, google-play-games, android-tv

I have an android game in Google Play.
Now I'm trying to make it compatible with Android TV.
I don't have any of the Android TV hardware. So I'm testing in emulator. I was able to start Android Emulator for Android TV with Android 5.0. My game is using Google Play Games Services. So to test it I need Google APIs in the emulator. But if I try to create an Android TV emulator with Google APIs I see no System images for Android TV with Google APIs.

Is it something that I am missing on my side or the Emulator doesn't support "Android TV with Google API"

Any info in this regard will be helpful.

**Edit**

I figured out the Android TV system images are having Google APIs by default.
But when I run my app (that uses Google Play Services) on the emulator I get the following message in an Alert Dialog

```
google play services which some of your applications rely on is not supported by your device
```

Also I saw the following somewhere in the logs.

```
google play services not available due to error 9
```

```
google play services is invalid. cannot recover"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No. I'm still having this problem. In fact I put my attempt at Android TV on hold since then.

Comment: any solution for your problem ?

Comment: @Code_Life I'm not perusing that project anymore and didn't follow up for a solution after some tries.

Answer (score 7):

Android TV Emulator with Play Services and Play Store is available on the latest AndroidTV Q image. It was recently [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/6-new-ways-to-engage-with-users-on.html):

> **Android TV Emulator with Play Store support:** Test your TV projects seamlessly. The Android TV emulator now supports Google Play, so you can test subscriptions faster through the emulator instead of testing on real devices.

Answer (score 3):

There is another answer related to accessing Google services and APIs, here:

[Google Play Services in emulator, implementing Google Plus login button etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc/17245326#17245326)

From the Android TV documentation, it seems that the emulators and TV add ons are not going to be available for every API version which means using Google APIs with the Android TV emulator is currently unsupported.

Comment: I could use emulator with Google APIs for normal android devices. Current situation is with "Android TV" emulators. After some research I found the Android TV emulators are having Google Play Services in it. But I'm getting alert message "google play services which some of your applications rely on is not supported by your device"

Comment: You need to find an emulator that includes Google APIs and that is compatible with Android TV. I'm not sure there is a working combination. What are you trying to do after you get the two working?

Comment: I want to test the "Google Play Games Services" I am using in the game. Details are given in the question. Also I've edited the question with recent findings.

Comment: Any progress with this? The google play services have stopped error is really annoying in the android tv emulator?

Comment: No update yet, still looks like the Android TV images do not have Google APIs enabled.

Comment: did you make any progress?