# Why is returning me NULL when I go to find map with FragmentManager?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, adt, gis

Hi when I am getting the map from Fragment Manager object, I go to find the map fragment, and it is returning null, why?

My code is:

```
public class MapaFragment extends Fragment  {
...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();

        return v;
    }
 ...
}
```

this code in mapFragment is null and obviously I can't get GoogleMap. LogCat give me NullPointer error in that line.

My fragment is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

permissions and manifest I think is right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="info.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="6171000" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>            
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ImagenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_imagen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting this screen:

[image]

The configuration screen I am using is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Google Play Services is required on the device that you are using to test. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245326/3358186) for a guide on setting up the emulator.**

Change the XML to of your layout to this, and take note of the name of the XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For example, if the file name was `map_fragment_layout.xml`, change your `View v` to the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){     
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout, null);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    GoogleMap map = mapView.getMap();

    return v;
}
```

**Another option: extend MapFragment**
This option is completely unrelated to the previous option. In this situation, you do not create, assign, or inflate an XML file. The view is generated programmatically.

```
public static class MapaFragment extends MapFragment {

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2){
        View v = super.onCreateView(arg0,arg1,arg2);
        mMap = getMap();
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I think you're not actually inflating the layout, since you're calling the super method.

Try to change

```
View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

to:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.id.yourLayout, container, false);
```

Note: replace `R.id.yourLayout`, with your fragment layout name.