# How can I fixed Get Google Play Services error in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm working with emulator on android studio about location services and api's but I have an error "This app won't run without Google Play Services , which are missing from your phone."

My emulator is Nexus 5 -- API Level 21(Android 5.0.1) -- ARM CPU and I downloaded sdk tools google APIs something.

Comment: you should create emulator using google API.and have you tested on device?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245326/1881611,

Comment: @Pragna How can I using google API with emulator on Android Studio IDE?

Comment: @Ishrat This question's answer about emulator api level but I'm working up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Android SDK Manager and check if this is installed:

Open the group Android 5.0.1 (API 21)
- Check Google APIs
- Check ARM EABI v7a System Image

Normally if this two artefacts are installed you can run it without problems.

If not, check also:
- Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools in Tools
- Android Support Library, Google Play Services and Google USB Driver in Extras

Comment: Thanks for answer . I checked these two artefacts and I haven't ARM EABI v7a System Image after that I install it , restarted Android Studio and Emulator  but I have same error. I installed all artefacts about Android 5.0.1 (API 21) but I can't solved it.

Comment: I change my post. Try please.

Comment: I installed your said artefacts but I have already same error.

Comment: Well... normally this solves your problem.
If your problem persists the best think to do will be use a physical device.

Comment: you try this solution? it results?

Comment: No I didn't try . My phone is broken. Thats why unfortunately I'm working with emultor.

Comment: ohhhh God! Bad luck! Go to amazon and buy a cheap phone. Is the best choice.