# google maps bluestacks android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, bluestacks

I am trying to develope an app using the google maps API for android. I have followed the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start. I am now trying to get something on screen.
I have tried ARC but that seems to have problems with google play services and more recently crashs before anything else
I have now been able to set up Bluestacks as an emulator for Android studio. But when I press run the app immediatly closes.
how can I prevent the app from crashing on Bluestacks?

Comment: The [standard virtual device emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html) with Google APIs is probably your best bet if you want to use Maps on a emulator. I believe it's only available for api levels 19+. Otherwise, I **highly** suggest you use an actual device.

Comment: do you mean the built in emulator in android studio? if so it doesn't seem to have google play services..........and is slow..........if i have to how do i get google play services working in there?

Comment: As long as you have the images installed through the SDK manager, the newer versions of Android can have Google Play Services already working. You may want to refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc).

Comment: i forgot mention that my computer has a AMD A8-3520m APU, nevertheless i'll try what is discribed in that question's answer

Comment: i have tried it but i only see a button "get google play services" and when clicking it it crashes on me........complete with "unfornately, mappy has stopped" dialog,,,,,,mappy being the name i gave it......... and um my only device has too little memory left to install an 60+mb google play services.........

Comment: thanks @Andy i have found that i needed to use an google API version of Android it is working fine now