# Android emulator with google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, emulation

I created an android emulator to test google play services, with the google apis 4.2.2 or greater like this article said
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup, but only google maps services is available, and the game I am testing claims for google play services. I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [google play services in 4.2.2 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc)

And I will suggest you to use Genymotion instead of using android default emulator. It is like virtual phone and you can also add Gapps in it as well as download any app from Google Play, same as android device.

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) and you can download google apps based on your virtual device version from this [Genymotion Gapps link](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145)

Comment: Genymotion is a paid application

Comment: @César Moltoni : No. You can use it's free version for personal use.
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Answer (score 0):

You have to run an emulator with Target: Google API´s
[image: AVD Manager]

Also be sure of compile this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

(Lastest version of google play services) If it doens't run, check for the verion of google play services on the emulator and change the version to compile.

Comment: I use eclipse with adt, but I compile with the correct libraries and use the google apis and does not work

Comment: Check the version of the google play services in the emulator, and compile that version or a previous one

Answer (score 0):

Start **SDK Manager**. **Check APIs** in android version you create emulator and **install it**. Open **SDK folder/system-images** and delete the emulator image. Start Emulator Manager and dowload new image **with api**. Start new emulator and it fixed.