# What is the latest issue about google play on emulator device?

Tags: android, google-play, android-sdk-tools, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded and installed android sdk

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#downloads

Then install everything in android api 23

However i can not find google play to install apps after i run the emulator

Isn't it possible with android SDK? via AVD manager?

Comment: Yep, definitely possible. This answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245326/5482166