# Google Maps in nativescript with angular2

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm new to nativescript and I've been trying to get google maps to work in it.

I downloaded a demo from github to see if it works.

https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk

But apparently it's outdated.
Google has changed the library of their play services and now i get the error message that it needs google play services to install maps when i have.

Is there a good tutorial how to install google maps or can i get a quick explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default emulator do not have `google play services` and if your try to deploy the app on it, you will receive an error. To be able to test the demo app, you can build in on real device or to setup [simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc) with available `google play service` .